# How can I get just the first half of an xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml:

```
<root>
 <elements>
  <element>
     <data1>Foo</data1>
     <data2>Bar</data2>
  </element>
  <element>
     <data1>Foo1</data1>
     <data2>Bar1</data2>
  </element>
  <element>
     <data1>Foo2</data1>
     <data2>Bar2</data2>
  </element>
  <element>
     <data1>Foo3</data1>
     <data2>Bar3</data2>
  </element>
 </elements>
</root>
```

I want to get the first half of the list in a structure (html table) and the second in another structure.

I am trying this:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
<xsl:variable name="set" select="elements/element" />
<xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)" />
<xsl:for-each select="elements/element" >
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $count div 2" >
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element" />
    </table>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:else>
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element" />
    </table>
  </xsl:else>                      
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have 2 issues:
1. else is not allowed in for-each. 
2. Is there a better solution for this besides counting the elements and using foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:variable name="set" select="elements/element" />
  <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)" />

    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$set[position() &lt; $count div 2]" />
    </table>

    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$set[position() >= $count div 2]" />
    </table>


</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, I realized right after I posted that I could go with

```
<table>
<xsl:apply-templates select='documents/document[(position()+1) mod 2 = 0]' />
</table>
<table>
<xsl:apply-templates select='documents/document[(position()+1) mod 2 = 1]' />
</table>
```

Martin's solution should work as well I think. I think it is fair to accept his solution even if mine does not require counting the elements.

NOTE: This solution will not solve the original issue. The first table will not contain the first half of the original xml, but the data on even positions in the original xml. The second table will contain the data on odd position. My original xml is not ordered, so this will work for me.

Comment: "*mine does not require counting the elements.*" Perhaps not, but it doesn't do what you asked for: "*get the first half of the list in a structure ... and the second in another structure.*"

Comment: yes, that is also true. but the xml is not actually ordered in any way, so I just wanted half in one table and half in the other. but you are right, if we are to keep the originaly stated requirement, Martin's solution is the correct one. this is why his answer will remain selected as the solution.

Comment: I am just saying that we know only what's in the question.

Comment: I concur and accepted the correct answer for the given question. This discussion makes no sense.

Comment: No one is attacking you; there's no need to become defensive/hostile.

Comment: I didn't become hostile. Did you feel threatened? I added a note to explain what my solution does and why it works for me. Are you happy now?